# Android activty not startring at second run

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities. One is the `LoginScreen` and other one is `MainScreen`. After login I am starting the MainScreen. The mainscreen runs a async tcp client in `onCreate` method. Then I am pressing back button to go LoginScreen. Then I am loging in again but the it says the TCPClient is null. I am getting a new instance of TCPClient when activity onCreate but it is being null. Here is my code.

```
//Main activity codes.
TCPClient mTcpClient;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            cnnTask = new connectTask();
            cnnTask.execute("");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
}
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {
 protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                srvrMessage = message;
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }
}
}
//LoginScreen code onClick.
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before at first login program is running. However when I go back to LoginScreen and try to login again new mTcpClient is being null.

I have tried to stop the mpTcpClient `onDestroy` and `onStop` method of MainScreen activity but it has not worked. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to move the `connectTask` creation and execution block from `onCreate` to `onResume` method.

Comment: Can't see the problem. Each time when start `MainScreen` new `TCPClient` will be created.

Comment: Yes it might create new connection but mTcpClient is being null :/

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. My TCP client server waits for until a byte comes from the server. Thus no matter to cancel the task. It waits for a byte to read. I have closed the stream `onCancelled` method of task and it works.